# Promise.all with array.map runs on parallel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an array of images, and what I am trying to do is manipulate all of those images with an image processing library using an asynchronous function.

My code works fine because every image in the array have a field called index, which represents it position in the array.

```
 // Adapt every image in the album to its dimensions
    await Promise.all(
      album.map(async (image) => {
        const adaptedImage = await adaptImageToAlbum(image);
        // Add the photo to the final album
        finalAlbum[image.index] = adaptedImage;
      })
    );
```

The thing is that if, instead, I use this code

```
 // Adapt every image in the album to its dimensions
    await Promise.all(
      album.map(async (image) => {
        const adaptedImage = await adaptImageToAlbum(image);
        // Add the photo to the final album
        finalAlbum.push(adaptedImage);
      })
    );
```

the finalAlbum is not sorted. Is there any other way to do that without using the first method I shared? I mean, do it sequentialy. And other thing, talking about performance, would it be better to do it as I did?

Comment: Have you tried this `await Promise.all(album.map((image) => adaptImageToAlbum(image)));` ?

Comment: When you say *sequentially*, do you mean one at a time, or do you mean in sequential order?

Comment: I agree with @HassanImam you should try that. The `map` will return an array with the result of the promise(s). See if that's your desired value.

Comment: Does it matter if the images are processed sequentially? Or do you just want the array sorted? If the latter, after the `await Promise.all`, run `finalAlbum.sort((a,b) => a.index - b.index)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the array before processing the items

```
const finalAlbum = await Promise.all(
  album
    .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
    .map((image) => adaptImageToAlbum(image));
);
```

As of performance it depends on the number of items you're processing.
In general it's better to avoid premature optimizations, as long as you don't have a performance issue, I would advise keeping the code clear and simple.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [BlueBird Promise.each](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html), through which the iteration will be performed sequentially, awaiting for any promises in the process:

```
const BlueBird = require("bluebird");

await BlueBird.each(album, async function(image) {
  const adaptedImage = await await adaptImageToAlbum(image);
  finalAlbum.push(adaptedImage);
})
```

To illustrate this directly, the following code fills the array in a random order:

```
const album = [1,2,3,4,5];

async function test(album) {
  let finalAlbum = [];
await Promise.all(
  album.map(async (image) => {
    const adaptedImage = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(image);
      }, Math.random() * 100);
    });
    finalAlbum.push(adaptedImage);
  })
)
console.log(finalAlbum);  //random order
}
```

Whereas with Bluebird it will always keep the original order:

```
const BlueBird = require("bluebird");

const album = [1,2,3,4,5];

async function test2(album) {
  let finalAlbum = [];
  await BlueBird.each(album, async function(image) {
      const adaptedImage = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(image);
        }, Math.random() * 100);
      });
      finalAlbum.push(adaptedImage);
    }
  )
  console.log(finalAlbum); // [1,2,3,4,5], keeps array order
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop for doing it sequentially.

```
  for (const image of album) {
    const adaptedImage = await adaptImageToAlbum(image);
    finalAlbum.push(adaptedImage);
  }
```